# String Splitting wrong output

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I wrote this simple program which splits a given input at every Non-Digit Character.

```
public class Fileread {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //Declarations
    String[] temp;
    String current;

    //Execution
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    while ((current = br.readLine()) != null) {
      temp = current.split("\\D"); //Splitting at Non Digits
      for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(temp[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the input.txt :

```
hello1world2  
world3  
end4of5world6
```

Output :

```
1




2





3



4

5




6
```

Why do so many extra spaces appear? I need to print each number on a separate line, without the spaces in between. How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `\\D+` pattern. However, a leading empty element may still be kept if your strings start with non-digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Declarations
        String[] temp;
        String current;

        //Execution
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d://input.txt"));
        while ((current = br.readLine()) != null) {
            temp = current.split("\\D+"); //Splitting at Non Digits
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                if (!temp[i].equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    System.out.println(temp[i]);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It worked! It's not working if I put !temp[i].equals(""). But it's working if I put !temp[i].equalsIgnoreCase(""). What's the Difference? Can you Explain?

Comment: My bad... It's working for **!temp[i].equals("")** also... Didn't try it... Anyway, Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

It is splitting at EACH and EVERY non-digit.

To treat strings of non-digits as one delimiter, specify

```
temp = current.split("\\D+");
```

instead.  Adding the plus-sign makes the pattern match one or more consecutive non-digit characters.

Answer (score 1):

In short, use

```
.replaceFirst("^\\D+","").split("\\D+")
```

Splitting the string with `\D` (a non-digit char matching pattern) means you match a **single non-digit char at a time**, and break the string at that char. When you need to split on a *chunk of characters*, you need to match *multiple consecutive* characters, and in your case, you just need to **add a `+` quantifier** after `\\D`.

However, that means that you will still have an empty element at Index 0 if your string has a non-digit(s) at the beginning of the string. The workaround is to **remove the substring at the start with the split pattern**.

The final solution is

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("hello1world2", "world3", "end4of5world6");
for (String str : strs) {
    System.out.println("---- Next string ----");
    String[] temp = str.replaceFirst("^\\D+","").split("\\D+");
    for (String s: temp) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

See the [online Java demo](http://ideone.com/kxn4lT)

Answer (score 0):

Java's [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method will create a token for each point appearing between two delimiters. Consider the following example:

```
String s = "a,b,c,,,f";
```

Because the delimiter `,` appears consecutively with nothing in between, `s.split(",")` produces the following output:

```
{"a", "b", "c", "", "", "f"}
```

You'll notice there are two blank strings in this array; a blank is inserted to represent the token that would've appeared between each pair of consecutive commas. Basically, the string is treated as `a,b,c,(blank),(blank),f`.

The solution for this is to have consecutive delimiters be treated as a single delimiter. Now, it's important to remember that your argument to `split` is actually a regular expression literal. So you can include the `+` greedy regex quantifier to tell the engine to match one or more consecutive delimiters, and treat them as a single split-point:

```
s.split(",+")
```

For the example above, this now yields the following (sans blank strings):

```
{"a", "b", "c", "f"}
```

You can apply a similar technique to your regex, using `\\D+`.